# Schedule overwriting itself

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

If the below 'delayingTest' is called N times, I expect it to eventually call doIt N times as well. However this is not the case, it seems as if the schedule overwrites any previous schedule, supposedly having the same selector. Anyway around this?

```
-(void)delayingTest {
    if (_delay) {
        [self schedule:@selector(delayingTest) interval:1.0f repeat:0 delay:1.0f];
    }
    else {
        [self doIt];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one way would be :
dont use _delay as `int` but bind it with timestamp storing it in `NSDate` and comparing the timestamps when next time your method gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
-(void)delayingTest
{
    if (_delay)
    {
        [self unschedule:@selector(delayingTest)];
        [self schedule:@selector(delayingTest) interval:1.0f];
    }
    else
    {
        [self doIt];
    }
}
```